# В Python в класс Battery нужно добавить метод upgrade_battery() . Он должен проверять размер батареи и устанавливать емкость 100 если она меньше 100

Tags: python

```py
class Car:
    """Простая попытка смоделировать машину."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Инициировать атрибут чтоб писует машину."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Вернуть отфарматированое содержимое имя """
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Вывести сообщение с пробегом автомобиля"""
        print(f"This car has {self.odometer_reading} miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage): # 2 Способ изменить знечение .
        """
        Задать значение одометра.
        Отклонить измену в случае попытки отмотать показатель одометра 
        """
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        """Додать заданое значение до показателя одометра"""
            
        self.odometer_reading += miles


class Battery:
    """Простая попытка смоделировать акамулятор електрокара"""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=75):
        """Создать атрибуты акамулятора"""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
        self.full_battery = 100


    def describe_battery(self):
        """Вывести сообщение про размер аккамулятора"""
        print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery.")

    def describe_full_battery(self):
        """Вывести сообщение про размер аккамулятора"""
        print(f"This car has a {self.full_battery}-kWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        """
        Вывести сообщение про растояние,
        которое может проехать авто 
        относительно до обьема батареи.
        """
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range = 260
        elif self.battery_size == 100:
            range = 315
        print(f"This car can go about {range} miles on a full charge.")

    def upgrade_battery(self):
        ...
        

class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Смоделировать характеристики, присущие електрокарам"""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):

        """
        Создать атрибуты базового класу
        Потом создать атрибуты електроавтомобиля
        """
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()
        

    def fill_gas_tank(self):
        """Електроавтомобили не имеют бензобаков"""
        print("This car doesn't need a gas tank!")


    my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
    my_i3 = ElectricCar('BMW', 'i3', 2020)


    print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
    my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
    my_tesla.fill_gas_tank()
    my_tesla.battery.get_range()

    print(my_i3.get_descriptive_name())
    my_i3.battery.get_range()
```

В класс `Battery` нужно добавить метод `upgrade_battery()`. Он должен проверять размер батареи и устанавливать емкость 100 если она меньше 100. Создать электрокар с уставным размером батареи и вызвать к нему метод `get_range()` и потом вызвать `get_range()` второй раз после обновления аккумулятора. В другом классе - `class ElectricCar(Car)`

Comment: Будьте добры прикрепить свой код не фотографией, а текстом, предварительно отформатировав его.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку батарея после вызова метода в любом случае будет равна 100, можно сразу задать значение 100:

```
def upgrade_battery(self):
    self.battery_size = 100
```

Comment: Можно и так но в задании написано что метод должен проверять размер батареи , а потом устанавливать его на 100 . Спасибо!!!

Comment: в таком случае напишите `def upgrade_battery(self) if self.battery_size < 100 self.battery_size = 100`

Comment: На мой взгляд тут имеется в виду, что возможен и такой случай, когда размер батареи **больше 100**, и тогда ваш метод отработает не так, как требуется, в этом случае вы не должны трогать размер батареи.

Comment: Странная батарея получится у этого электромобиля если её заряд 101%

Comment: @valixxx А, ну если так, то да. Всё-таки что такое `battery_size` - не очень понятно, я бы скорее подумал, что это объём, ну там в миллиампер/час, например. А заряд обычно называют `charge`. Да и апгрейд как-то с зарядом не ассоциируется, а вот с объёмом - да.

Comment: Кстати, я же действительно прав: "This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery" - это объём, а не заряд. Да, так совпало, что тут только два объёма 75 и 100 и можно подумать, что больше 100 не бывает, но нет, это таки объём и он может быть любым, и больше 100 тоже может быть теоретически, хотя в этом коде не прописано, например, отображение проходимого расстояния для других значений объёма аккумулятора.

Answer (score 0):

```
def upgrade_battery(self):
    if self.battery_size <= 100:
        self.battery_size = 100
```

> Правильный ответ?

```
def upgrade_battery(self):
    if self.battery_size <= 100:
        self.battery_size == 100
```

> А я вводил так . Тупняк конкретный ))))

Comment: Программист всё должен делать тщательно. У вас в условии задачи чётко написано "если меньше 100", а не "если меньше или равно 100". Вроде мелочь и здесь это вроде как не важно, но в следующий раз может и не повезти с этим.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание!